# Adding array elements to object's key and values

Tags: javascript, arrays

If i have the following array

```
const Array = ['Michael', 'student', 'John', 'cop', 'Julia', 'actress']
```

How could i make an object like

```
const Object = {
Michael: student,
John: cop, 
Julia: actress,
}
```

Is there a way to make the even index elements to be the object's keys and the odd index elements to be the key's values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple for loop that steps by two indexes at a time would work.

Try like below

```js
const array = ['Michael', 'student', 'John', 'cop', 'Julia', 'actress'];

const output = {}

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i+=2){
  output[array[i]] = array[i+1]
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = ['Michael', 'student', 'John', 'cop', 'Julia', 'actress'];

let obj={};

arr.forEach((element, index) => {

  if(index % 2 === 0){

    obj[element] = arr[index+1];

  }
})

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the array into chunks of size 2 and then convert it to an object with `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
let arr = ['Michael', 'student', 'John', 'cop', 'Julia', 'actress'];
let obj = Object.fromEntries([...Array(arr.length / 2)]
            .map((_, i)=>arr.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2)));
console.log(obj);
```